# What does the ampersand do here?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, reference

I'm trying to understand this section of code, and I've come across something I just cannot interpret:

```
template<unsigned ELEMENT_DIM, class SIM, unsigned SPACE_DIM>
void CellBasedSimulationArchiver<ELEMENT_DIM, SIM, SPACE_DIM>::Save(SIM* pSim)
{
    // Do a bunch of stuff

    boost::archive::text_oarchive* p_arch = arch_opener.GetCommonArchive();

    // Archive the simulation (const-ness would be a pain here)
    (*p_arch) & pSim;  //<--------------- What is this?
}
```

The point of this function is to archive the state of a simulation using boost, so it can be reloaded at a later time and continued. I'm trying to understand how the archiving actually happens, but the line with the arrow baffles me. At some point the actual saving has to happen, and I guess the arrow is where it happens.

Something must be going on with boost, but what exactly does this line mean and what does the `&` do here? Is it some kind of reference? I looked at [some documentation](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-archive) and it contains the `<<` operator, but nowhere is there a `&`

Comment: The link you provide does contain this, namely `ar & a.legs_;`. It also has text above that code example.

Comment: Intuition tells me it calls [`operator&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) on the object stored at `p_arch`, but it looks a little weird to me, so I'm not 100% sure. Particularly because calling `operator &` here usually means nothing on a normal object. But boost may do something different.

Comment: The boost serialization library is a good example of how abusing operator overloading leads to pain.

Comment: @chris Ok, I found the part you are talking about, but I'm still none the wiser

Comment: @Phill, I'm not too familiar with the library, but *With operator& there is no need to distinguish between serializing and restoring within serialize().* Going by that, it sounds primarily for convenience. I'd also recommend going through the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). What you linked to is a book about Boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand here is the binary `&` operator. For integer types, this would be the bitwise AND operator (just like `<<` would be the left-shift operator), but `boost::archive::text_oarchive` is not an integer type. There must have been an operator overload function defined for this class. Thus, this operator will invoke that function.

According to the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/archives.html):

> ```
> sa << x
> sa & x
> ```
>
> These expressions must perform exactly the same function. They append the value of x along with other information to sa. This other information is defined by the implementation of the archive. Typically this information is that which is required by a corresponding Loading Archive type to properly restore the value of x.

So, `(*p_arch) & pSim;` appends `pSim` into the archive pointed by `p_arch`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's actually cleared up a whole heap of misconceptions I had about the archiving-related functions in this package as well... now I'm going for a break and to ponder on why someone would do this!